# How to get Azure DevOps Deployments to work when using approval gate?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I am trying to learn automating Salesforce Deployments using Azure DevOps. Below are two yaml one of which works and other doesn't.

This works: I am not using approval gates here.

```
pr:
  autoCancel: "true"
  branches:
    include:
    - sprint1
    - main
  paths:
    exclude:
    - README.md
    - azure-pipelines.yml
stages:
- stage: TestSalesforceOrg
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/sprint1'))
  jobs:
  - job: DeployInBetaOrg
    steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '14.x'
              checkLatest: true
          - bash: 
              npm install sfdx-cli --global
            displayName: Install Salesforce CLI
          - bash:
                sfdx config:set restDeploy=false --global
            displayName: Use SOAP API for Deployment
          - bash:
                sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --client-id <Client Id> --jwt-key-file ./bin/server.key --username <Username> --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com
            displayName: Authorize Salesforce DeployTestOrg Org
          - bash:
                sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app -w 10 -u <Username>
            displayName: Deploy source code to DeployTestOrg Org
```

Below does not work: I am using approval gate here:

```
pr:
  autoCancel: "true"
  branches:
    include:
    - sprint1
    - main
  paths:
    exclude:
    - README.md
    - azure-pipelines.yml
stages:
- stage: TestSalesforceOrg
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/sprint1'))
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployInBetaOrg
    environment: "BetaOrg"
    strategy:
     runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '14.x'
              checkLatest: true
          - bash: 
              npm install sfdx-cli --global
            displayName: Install Salesforce CLI
          - bash:
                sfdx config:set restDeploy=false --global
            displayName: Use SOAP API for Deployment
          - bash:
                sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --client-id <Client Id> --jwt-key-file ./bin/server.key --username <username> --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com
            displayName: Authorize Salesforce DeployTestOrg Org
          - bash:
                sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app -w 10 -u <username>
            displayName: Deploy source code to DeployTestOrg Org
```

Below is the error though server.key file is in the location else first YAML should have failed:

[image]